# Wrong argument count for function call: 2 arguments given but expected 1

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethers.js

```
    uint256 adminTokenBalance = balanceOf(owner(), tokenId);
    require(adminTokenBalance > 0, "Admin does not hold expired token");

    _transfer(owner(), msg.sender, tokenId, adminTokenBalance, "");
}
```

issue in require() Wrong argument count for function call: 2 arguments given but expected 1.(6160)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure without actual compiler output, but the "reason" parameter has not always existed in `require()`. Are you using a very old compiler version?